# Sunspot Solr Rails - Search Multiple Models using 'with'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, solr, sunspot

I'm having some success sutting up Solr in my App. I've managed to search across two models but am now trying to fine tune my search using 'with' clauses.

My event model has:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
   text :headline, :info
   time :event_date
  end
end
```

My venue model has:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
   text :name, :address_1, :address_2, :town, :postcode
  end
end
```

And then I have a search controller where I previously managed to return both events and venues based my `params[:search]`. I'm now trying to return forthcoming events and venues but as there's no 'event_date' in venues I now only get the events back. In short, how do I make `with(:event_date)` apply to the Event model only?

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @search = Sunspot.search [Event, Venue] do
      fulltext params[:search]
      with(:event_date).greater_than(Time.zone.now)
    end
    @results = @search.results
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @results }
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: +1 Starred Would like to see some thoughts on this as well

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to add this field to the other "searchable" like this:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
   text :name, :address_1, :address_2, :town, :postcode
   time :event_date { Time.zone.now }
  end
end
```

you can put whatever you want in the { #here }

Hope it helps

Comment: ``` time :event_date do Time.zone.now end```                              Ideal would have been to have some scoped queries from within sunspot and then combining results.

Comment: Could you clarify what adding the block allows you to do? Does that allow OP to do what he wanted?